# for loop for time

Tags: java, date, datetime, for-loop

I am having problem in creating a function like this in Java:

```
for(i=initial Time ; i<some final time ; i imcrement by 15 sec )
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

any suggestions are cordially accepted.

---

The requirement is that we generate different time values increased by 15 seconds , its not like we need to execute every 15 seconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need different time values incremented by 15s then:

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long end = now + (60 * 1000);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

for (long i = now; i < end; i += 15000) {

    c.setTimeInMillis(i);
    System.out.println(c.getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recomend you to use the currentTimeMillis and the long time format in java

Example:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class TestTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long initialTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long finalTime = initialTime + 30*1000*60;//half an hour later

        for(long i=initialTime ; i<finalTime ; i+=15*1000)
        {
            System.out.println(new Date(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need a time-based representation. I would perhaps look at Joda-Time's [LocalTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) class and in particular the [plusSeconds(](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html#plusSeconds%28int%29)) method. I wouldn't use the standard Java time/date based stuff for numerous reasons (poor API, mutable state etc.)

If you want something similar but without so much type-safety, just use `Thread.currentTimeMillis()` and add 15000 (15 secs) each loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `Calander api` in `while` loop like -

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(startDate);
cal1.setTime(endDate);
while (!cal.equals(cal1)) {
  cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
  if(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)==Calendar.SATURDAY)
     System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
  System.out.println(cal.getTime());

}
```

Comment: yeas exactly , but here its generating date for every date passed , i need to create a date string after every 15 secs , any help ??

Answer (score 0):

Requirement changed (The requirement is that we generate different time values increased by 15 seconds , its not like we need to execute every 15 seconds,)
therefore this is not correct answer.

```
int start=0;
int end= 10;
for(int i=start ; i<end ; i++)
{
   System.out,println(i*15);
   try {

       Thread.sleep(15000); // 15000 miliseconds

   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();     
   }
}
```

Comment: Now you need to change `i` to be an integer and increment it by `i++`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
for (long stop=System.currentTimeMillis();stop<System.currentTimeMillis()+60;stop=stop+15) 
{
//code to execute
}
```

Thus this loop will execute 4 times.

Comment: "Thus this loop will execute 4 times" - no it doesn't, it executes 5 times. The way it is programmed it might even vary!

Comment: @xagyg: Ohh really!! teall me how?Have you even tried to execute it.

Comment: yes I executed it ... here is the output ... 1354622912004
1354622912019
1354622912034
1354622912049
1354622912064

Comment: Then You might be executing it with <= conditions.Go and correct it.Try printing some string within the loop after correction.You will get your answer.

Answer (score -1):

"The requirement is that we generate different time values increased by 15 seconds , its not like we need to execute every 15 seconds" ... so here it is ...

```
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();       // now
    long stop = start + 60000;                     // 60 seconds later
    long interval = 15000;                         // 15 second interval
    for (long i = start; i < stop; i+=interval) {
            System.out.println(new Date(i));
    }
```